# Setting %nullind rpg using one line

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Is there a way in RPG to assign a boolean value in one line without a if statement?

for example in C# you can do:

```
bool x = (some condition = true);
```

is there a way to do something like this in rpg:

```
 %nullind(FIELD) = (FIELD=="");
```

Is this the right way (only way):

```
 *in01 = (Somevalue=AnotherValue);
  %nullind(field) = *in01;
```

Also,

when I initially turn ON the nullind do I have to turn it off in order to get the field to update to a non-null value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, make the assignment to an indicator type variable (type N).

```
*in01 = (somevalue = anothervalue);
```

Comment: so that would still be more than two lines which is ok..  would it be something like:  *inO1 = (SOMEVALUE=AnotherValue); %nullind(field) = %in01;

Comment: Have you tried doing: `%nullind(field) = (somevalue = anothervalue);` ?